# ElasticSearch advanced query_string query

Tags: elasticsearch, querydsl, elasticsearch-query

What I need is, elastic should search in **multiple fields and return data by field priority.**

For example: For the search string `obil hon`,  elastic should search in fields[title, description, modelCaption] and return data when at first it finds `Mobile Phone` in `Title` field, then in other fields.

Query I use:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_operator": "or",
            "fields": [
              "title^5",
              "description",
              "modelCaption",
              "productFeatureValues.featureValue",
              "productFeatureValues.featureCaption"
            ],
            "query": "*obil* *hone*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 16
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [multi-match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) to query multiple fields and it supports boosting a particular field like a `title` in your case and different operators like `OR` in your case.

Sample ES query for your use case:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match" : {
      "query" : "mobile phones",
      "fields" : [ "title^5", "description","modelCaption","productFeatureValues.featureVal"],
      "fuzziness" : "AUTO" --> Adding fuzziness to query
    }
  }
}
```

Here title filed is boosted by factor 5, hence if mobile phones match in title field then it would be scored higher.

**Also please note, you are using wild-card in your query string which is very costly so it's better to avoid them if you can.**

**EDIT:** Based on OP comments, included [fuzziness parameter AUTO](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#fuzziness) in query for better results

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a task that searching should work on uncompleted words, like "obile" or "hone", that's why I need query that supports that kind of search. in multi_match query I cant achieve this

Comment: @AlexanderMchedlishvili, that's a different requirement given in your question :-) , btw match query is analyzed query and it can give you results for uncompleted words given you have n-grams analyzer for these fields :-)

Comment: My native language is not supported in Elasticsearch. So, I need a way to achieve this without language analyzer

Comment: ngram is not a language analyzer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html please have a look, I can provide you working example if you provide some sample documents and expected results

Comment: @AlexanderMchedlishvili did you get a chance to go through my latest comment, please follow-up on your questions in order to get the help from community

Comment: After communication to business I ended up with multi match query with fuzziness parameter. Thank you for your help! I appreciate it. Please, edit your comment with fuzziness option, I will mark as answer.